# C++ std::map how to access keys by index location

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I would like to use C++ `std::map` to access the value associated to a given key in log(n) time. Since the keys of a `std::map` are sorted, technically, I can access the keys by the location in the sorted order. 
I know std::map does not have a random access iterator. Is there any "map like" data structure providing both access through the keys (by using the [] operator) and also providing the (read-only) random access though the location of the key in the sorted order. Here is a basic example:

```
my_fancy_map['a'] = 'value_for_a'
my_fancy_map['b'] = 'value_for_b'

assert my_fancy_map.get_key_at_location(0) == 'a'
assert my_fancy_map.get_key_at_location(1) == 'b'
assert my_fancy_map.get_value_at_location(1) == 'value_for_b'
assert my_fancy_map['a'] == 'value_for_a'
```

Comment: I recommend reading through a good data structures book, maybe an advanced one also.

Comment: There is no index in a map

Comment: You can use a sorted `vector<pair>`, use `std::lower_bound` to access by key.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want that?

Comment: There is no `random` or direct access with a `map`.  Consider that many implementations use a `red-black` tree, which has links.  Trying to find the 10th node is time consuming, at best.

Comment: Keep a *sorted vector* and use binary searches (like lower_bound). Wrap that in a class.

Comment: Do you still want O(logn) insertions? Note that with the sorted vector recommendation independent insertions will be O(n), though you would have the option to do batch insertions at O(nlogn) by pushing back all the elements and then sorting.

Comment: A [`boost::multi_index::ranked_unique`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnk_indices) structure has logarithmic by key *and* logarithmic by index lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Boost.MultiIndex's [ranked indices](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnk_indices):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5e1a65715d0d2ce)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ranked_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

template<typename K,typename T>
using ranked_map=multi_index_container<
  std::pair<K,T>,
  indexed_by<
    ranked_unique<member<std::pair<K,T>,K,&std::pair<K,T>::first>>
  >
>;

#include <cassert>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  ranked_map<std::string,std::string> m;

  m.emplace("a","value for a");
  m.emplace("b","value for b");

  assert(m.nth(0)->first=="a");
  assert(m.nth(1)->first=="b");
  assert(m.nth(1)->second=="value for b");
  assert(m.find("a")->second=="value for a");
}
```

Note, however, that `nth` is not O(1) but logarithmic, so ranked indices are not exactly random-access.

**Postscript:** Another alternative with true random access is Boost.Container's [flat associative containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b060201918ccb0b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  boost::container::flat_map<std::string,std::string> m;

  m["a"]="value for a";
  m["b"]="value for b";

  assert(m.nth(0)->first=="a");
  assert(m.nth(1)->first=="b");
  assert(m.nth(1)->second=="value for b");
  assert(m["a"]=="value for a");
}
```

The downside here is that insertion takes linear rather than logarithmic time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you happen to know if there is a benchmark on boost::multi-index?

Comment: Benchmark against what? You might find this presentation useful: http://www.mkrevuelta.com/m/pdf/UsingStdCpp_2017_MartinKR_SuperTree_16_9.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate through them:

```
my_fancy_map['a'] = 'value_for_a'
my_fancy_map['b'] = 'value_for_b'

auto location = std::begin(my_fancy_map);
assert location.first == 'a'
++location;
assert location.first == 'b'
assert location.second == 'value_for_b'
assert my_fancy_map['a'] == 'value_for_a'
```